# How to immediately exit from exec command via context cancellation?

Tags: go

I am streaming command output to a client with this code. The command is built with context cancellation. The client sends a "cancel" request to the server which notifies the client's `cancelCh` which triggers `cancel()`.

The issue I'm having is when the command is cancelled, the rest of the command output streams to the client as if the command was not cancelled. After the command is completed, `exit status 1` is received; which shows that the command was indeed cancelled.

If I move the `done` channel to block after `cmd.Wait()` instead of before, I get the behavior I expect. The client immediately gets `exit status 1` and no more data is sent. But that seems to cause a data race issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19685. That issue is old but I think it's relevant.

What is the proper way to stream output to the client in real-time while also immediately exiting via context cancellation?

```
go func() {
    defer func() {
       cancel()
    }()
    <-client.cancelCh
}()

output := make(chan []byte)
go execute(cmd, output)

for data := range output {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n\n", data)
    flusher.Flush()             
}
```

```
func execute(cmd *exec.Cmd, output chan []byte) {
    defer close(output)

    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting stdout pipe: %v", err))
        return
    }
    cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            output <- scanner.Bytes()
        }
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error executing: %v", err))
        return
    }

    <-done

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        output <- []byte(err.Error())
    }

    //<-done
}
```

Comment: Where is any context in your `execute`? Or what exactly does `cancel()` cancels?

Comment: @zerkms A different function builds the command via ```exec.CommandContext(ctx, name, args...)```. That function returns the ```cmd``` and the ```context.CancelFunc``` which are used here.

Comment: So, where in `execute` is any use of a context?

Comment: @zerkms None directly. My thinking is that when ```<-client.cancelCh``` is received, the ```cancel``` associated with the ```cmd``` in ```execute``` cancels the command, which should immediately error or EOF the scanner, etc. That's what happens when ```<-done``` is moved to after ```cmd.Wait()``` so I think that relationship is there, but that causes a data race.

Comment: See the line 520 at https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=14689:14715#L520: `cmd.Wait` closes the file descriptors. Before it's done - they are open, hence scanner continues trying to read from them. Why do you even have `done` channel there at all?

Comment: @zerkms As a safety net so the scanner doesn't try to send on closed ```output```. I wanted to block on ```done``` and then close ```output```.

Comment: Then make `done` a buffered channel of size 1 and move `<-done` to the very end

Comment: @atye The code in the question has a data race on the scanner's buffer. The underlying array of the slice returned by Scanner.Bytes can be overwritten by the next call to Scanner.Scan.  The main goroutine can read the underlying array concurrently with those overwrites.   You can reduce the complexity of the code by eliminating goroutines.  See  https://play.golang.org/p/flKF6NADQ3U for an example.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I will need a go routine somewhere in here. Your playground example blocks on the scanner even if the command is context cancelled.  I modified it to run cmd.Wait in a go routine which will close the scanner immediately and write the error: [link]https://play.golang.org/p/NX-t4VdNu6A. Also, I don't quite understand the data race but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I understand. I was sending the underlying byte slice to ```output``` which could be overwritten by the scanner. If I want to use the channels, I should copy the slice into a temporary buffer and send that. But I like your example. I don't think there will be any issues with my cmd.Wait modification.

Comment: I apologize for sending you in the wrong direction about eliminating the last goroutine.  Your playground link has data race on writing to response writer.  Move all response writer writes to main goroutine.  See https://play.golang.org/p/5CGSDxvTM2t.